# Horizon DB Initialized with Arbitrary Base(?)

Tags: horizon

Settings: Private network, 4 nodes running good and validating each other. Now I try to add a 5th node for testing, upon encountering an [Horizon ingestion issue](https://github.com/stellar/go/issues/335).

---

> this is how I made the node "5a" (there is also a "5b")

Step 1, made a copy from the one of the 4 existing nodes

Step 2, clear all DB ; IP changed ; NODE_SEED changed ; stellar-core.cfg set to have 5 validators (4 existing + itself) and CATCHUP_COMPLETE=true

Step 3, reboot and start this 5th node

After a while, the following appeared at the Horizon log:

Looks strange that

```
time="2018-03-15T11:07:29+08:00" level=warning msg="ingest: waiting for stellar-core sync" pid=1593
time="2018-03-15T11:07:30+08:00" level=warning msg="ingest: waiting for stellar-core sync" pid=1593
time="2018-03-15T11:07:31+08:00" level=warning msg="ingest: waiting for stellar-core sync" pid=1593
time="2018-03-15T11:07:32+08:00" level=info msg="history db is empty, establishing base at ledger 2" pid=1593
time="2018-03-15T11:07:36+08:00" level=info msg="ingest: already in progress" pid=1593
time="2018-03-15T11:07:38+08:00" level=info msg="ingest: already in progress" pid=1593
time="2018-03-15T11:07:40+08:00" level=info msg="ingest: already in progress" pid=1593
```

As it looked strange that Horizon counted from **ledger 2**, I repeated the above steps except the IP was different. At this node "5b" (also only 5 validators), Horizon started its base from **ledger 41**.

```
time="2018-03-15T12:01:38+08:00" level=warning msg="ingest: waiting for stellar-core sync" pid=1592
time="2018-03-15T12:01:39+08:00" level=warning msg="ingest: waiting for stellar-core sync" pid=1592
time="2018-03-15T12:01:40+08:00" level=warning msg="ingest: waiting for stellar-core sync" pid=1592
time="2018-03-15T12:01:41+08:00" level=info msg="history db is empty, establishing base at ledger 41" pid=1592
time="2018-03-15T12:01:45+08:00" level=info msg="ingest: already in progress" pid=1592
time="2018-03-15T12:01:47+08:00" level=info msg="ingest: already in progress" pid=1592
time="2018-03-15T12:01:49+08:00" level=info msg="ingest: already in progress" pid=1592
```

Any idea what went wrong..?

Comment: Just set up one more control experiment: level=info msg="history db is empty, establishing base at ledger 86". These varying numbers are perplexing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given how stellar-core populates its `txhistory` and `txfeehistory` tables (as a queue containing arbitrary gaps), the horizon history system establishes its elder ledger at the stellar-core latest ledger when initializing an empty horizon database.  This behavior is to help reliability and lower admin intervention across most configurations.  To backfill the skipped ledgers, run the `horizon db backfill COUNT` command against your installation.

While not specifically mentioning this behavior, the reference docs for ingestion are here:  https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/admin.html#ingesting-stellar-core-data

Comment: Thanks Scott, I will try your solution later when I came back to this issue. Last week I just reset everything as I observed this behavior.

Comment: Is it possible to not skip any ledgers? Backfilling takes days/weeks.